# Show image from POST response in angular with spring boot backend

Tags: html, angular, typescript, httprequest

I'm new to the topic of http requests.

I am uploading an image from the client and send it to the server via a POST request. I should get an image back in the answer, because it works fine in Postman. Unfortunately it doesn't work in my code because the answer is not showing. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be this line? I think the body contains the entire image contents, judging by the postman response, require the raw postman response to be sure.

Before:

```
this.dbImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.postResponse.image;
```

After:

```
this.dbImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.postResponse.body;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @Stephan Please share postman raw response

Comment: Shared it in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now:

> **My browser showed an error I didn't see before:**
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/maze' from origin >'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control->Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> To solve this, I added `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")` to
> the spring boot controler. Now it can reach the server.